# Django: Populating ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I have been searching up and down and I can't seem to find the right answer.

I have been playing around with django and with my test project and I can't figure out how to implement this, I am trying to display dropdown contents dynamically based on foreign key from my views

Here is my sample views:

```
def job_display(request):

    job_list = Job_Posting.objects.filter(Publication_Status="A", Available_Slots__gt=0).order_by('-Urgency_Status', '-Date_Modified')
    context = {'job_list': job_list}
    return render(request, 'frontend/home.html', context)

def save_page(request, job_id):
    jreq = get_object_or_404(Job_Posting, fkey=job_id)
    form = application_form(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        .....
    else:
        .....
    return render(request, 'frontend/apply.html ... )
```

My urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.job_display, name='job_display'),
    url(r'^(?P<job_id>[0-9]+)/apply$', views.save_page, name='save_page'),
)
```

My froms:

```
class edbackgound(ModelForm):
    COURSE = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Educational_Requirement.objects.all())
```

my models:

```
class Course_Selection(models.Model):
    Course = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    Abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Job(models.Model):
    Job_Position = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, unique=True)

class Job_Posting(models.Model):
    fkey = models.OneToOneField(Job, verbose_name="Job Positions")
    ....

class Educational_Requirement(models.Model):
    fkey = models.OneToOneField(Job_Posting, verbose_name="Job Positions")
    Ed_req = models.OneToOneField(Course_Selection, verbose_name = 'Educational Requirement')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Ed_req
```

My problem is displaying the choices in modelform, in my views I can get the currently selected `job_list` through `save_page`'s `jreq` via `jreq.fkey` where I can just get it's `Job_position` then save my form. How can I populate my form's `ModelChoiceField` through my selected `job_list`.

If my post is not clear, please, feel free to comment what my post lacks

**EDIT**
I have found out that you can set your `queryset` via views like this:

`form.fields['COURSE'].queryset = Educational_Requirement.objects.filter(fkey=jreq.fkey_id)`

My problem with that is I am using an `inlineformset_factory` to generate my fields dynamically, and if I do this:

```
for form in myinlineform:
    form.fields['COURSE'].queryset = Educational_Requirement.objects.filter(fkey=jreq.fkey_id)`
```

I am raising an error that says: `[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included the management form for your inline formset in your template:

```
{{ my_formset.management_form }}
```

Read more on it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform

Comment: Yes, I have `{{ my_formset.management_form }} `, my test application works fine without the `for`